# Backbone.js collection fetch not setting response objects as models

Tags: backbone.js, collections, fetch

When fetching a collection, my api response has 10 objects, but the resulting Backbone collection only has 1 model with an attributes array containing the 10 response objects....to put it another way, the fetch is not creating models out of the objects in my response...and I don't know why.

Model definition:

```
MyApp.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){

    }
});
```

Collection definition:

```
MyApp.ItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyApp.Item,
    url: '/api/v1/item/',
    parse : function(response){
        //api returns objects in the content attribute of response, need to override parse
        return response.content;  
    }
});
```

Calling fetch:

```
var myCollection = new MyApp.ItemCollection();

myCollection.fetch({
    traditional: true,
    data: {  //url params for api call
        u_id: currentUser.id,
        order: 'sort_date:desc',
        start: 0,
        num_items: 10,
        format:'json'}
    });
```

Results:

**console.log(response.content);**

```
4571221007823F95BAAFB2BDF81111XX: Object
0124207763051005AAF59694458EBFXX: Object
3324207755431003B589CEF237DBE1XX: Object
3470000061641005BFB5D9983156E0XX: Object
3515553061641005A02884677F5624XX: Object
3526033426761006AFEA9852B0DDB5XX: Object
21431252714010079E4D8413429DB0XX: Object
26570547220410068F60D1B07D2E08XX: Object
37557124663710079DDC81EE855981XX: Object
0152243312031007957B94F5073B69XX: Object

//api successfully returns an array of objects, with GUID as key
```

**console.log(myCollection);**

```
r {length: 1, models: Array[1], _byId: Object}

//why only one model? why not 10?
```

**console.log(myCollection.models[0].attributes);**

```
4571221007823F95BAAFB2BDF81111XX: Object
0124207763051005AAF59694458EBFXX: Object
3324207755431003B589CEF237DBE1XX: Object
3470000061641005BFB5D9983156E0XX: Object
3515553061641005A02884677F5624XX: Object
3526033426761006AFEA9852B0DDB5XX: Object
21431252714010079E4D8413429DB0XX: Object
26570547220410068F60D1B07D2E08XX: Object
37557124663710079DDC81EE855981XX: Object
0152243312031007957B94F5073B69XX: Object
__proto__: Object

//there they are...but why?
```

How can I change the fetch to get these objects added as individual models in myCollection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response must be an array. Each item in the array is turned into a model. Your response is an object.

Update your parse method to pull out the values (as an array) from the response into an array and it'll work.

```
MyApp.ItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyApp.Item,
    url: '/api/v1/item/',
    parse : function(response){
        //api returns objects in the content attribute of response, need to override parse
        return _.map(response.content, function(model, id) {
            model.id = id;
            return model;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Cory, you are a gentleman and a scholar.  That worked.   Any guidance on how to set the models' id attributes to the GUIDs in the response?

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling you'd need to do that. 1 sec, lemme edit the post

Comment: Is the array key for the models array always going to be an integer index in Backbone collections?  I'm used to overriding the array keys with GUIDs for easy access...is that bad form in Backbone?

Comment: Nah, the ID can be anything. string, guid, number, doesn't matter -- it just has to be unique.